# Show that maximum of two random variables is a random variable

Tags: probability, random-variable, measure-theory

If we have that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, how do we prove that $Z=max(X,Y)$ is also a random variable ? I want to do this by showing that $Z$ is measurable, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: @Xi'an It is a bit more subtle than that when you are doing measure-theoretic probability. It isn't enough for $max()$ to be a function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One has
$$
\max(a,b) = \frac{|a-b| + a + b}{2}.
$$
So the function $(a,b) \mapsto \max(a,b)$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, hence measurable.

Now the pair $(X,Y)$ is a $\mathbb{R}^2$-valued random variable. Hence its composition with $\max$ is measurable.

---

Or you can directly show the measurability. Let $M = \max(X,Y)$. It is enough to show that the sets $\{M \leqslant t\}$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ are measurable. One has
$$
\{M \leqslant t\} = \{X \leqslant t\} \cap \{Y \leqslant t\}.
$$
This is the intersection of two measurable sets, hence a measurable set.

Comment: I should have been more clear. It is defined on the probability space $([0,1], \mathcal{B}_{[0,1]}, \mu_L)$